# MySQL: Order By Specific Fields

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

First question ever so be harsh :)

I am needing to sort by a specific department type or department(s) followed by rank.
The default setting orders by Rank, Dept_Type and Department. The front end is PHP but I'm looking more for a SQL fix if possible.  I also have a source table of departments if a sub query could work.

Orgin Table:

```
+-----------+------------+------+
| Dept_Type | Department | Rank |
+-----------+------------+------+
| Inbound   | Dept R     |   1  |
| Outbound  | Dept P     |   2  |
| Inbound   | Dept E     |   3  |
| Outbound  | Dept D     |   4  |
| Outbound  | Dept D     |   5  |
| Outbound  | Dept D     |   6  |
+-----------+------------+------+
```

I need to specify to order by "Dept D", "Dept E", then everything else like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY FIELD(department, "Dept D", "Dept E"), Rank, Dept_Type, Department
```

What I want it to return (DDDERP):

```
+-----------+------------+------+
| Dept_Type | Department | Rank |
+-----------+------------+------+
| Outbound  | Dept D     |   4  |
| Outbound  | Dept D     |   5  |
| Outbound  | Dept D     |   6  |
| Inbound   | Dept E     |   3  |
| Inbound   | Dept R     |   1  |
| Outbound  | Dept P     |   2  |
+-----------+------------+------+
```

What it actually returns(RPDDDE):

```
+-----------+------------+------+
| Dept_Type | Department | Rank |
+-----------+------------+------+
| Inbound   | Dept R     |   1  |
| Outbound  | Dept P     |   2  |
| Outbound  | Dept D     |   4  |
| Outbound  | Dept D     |   5  |
| Outbound  | Dept D     |   6  |
| Inbound   | Dept E     |   3  |
+-----------+------------+------+
```

So in theory I want:

```
ORDER BY FIELD("Dept D", "Dept E", department), Rank
```

But it obviously does not work that way.  Thank you for taking time to look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DESC attribute:

`ORDER BY FIELD(department, 'Dept E', 'Dept D') DESC, Rank, Dept_Type, Department`

Comment: Holy crap, it was literally that easy.  Thanks